# Excel VBA pass arguments to Python script

Tags: python, excel, vba

I want to start a Python script from Excel VBA. I have this

```
Sub RunPython()

    Dim PythonExe As String, PythonScript As String, PythonArgs As String
    Dim objShell As Object
    
    PythonExe = "C:\MyProgs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
    PythonScript = "c:\scripts\Python\test.py"
    PythonArgs = "1 1"

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript
    'objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript & " " & PythonArgs
    
End Sub
```

The Python script is written in a way to accept arguments on the command line or to prompt the user if no arguments are given.
The first objShell.run ... works, it starts the script and waits for user input.
The second objShell.run ... does not work. The shell flashes and that's it.
If I call the python script from the command line directly like this

```
test.py 1 1
```

the script works.

So, how can I pass the arguments to the script using VBA?
Ultimately, I want to read the two arguments from an Excel sheet and pass them.

I've read
[Pass Python Argument Through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458304/pass-python-argument-through-vba)

Comment: If you pass arguments into the Python script, does it wait for user input? Is it possible the script is completing so quickly that the shell only appears and disappears?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. In the Python script, I switched from positional arguments to optional. As a result, I need to send the arguments like this

```
PythonArgs = "--arg1 1 --arg2 1"
```