# Shell does not run python script on being called from VBA sub

Tags: python, python-3.x, vba

I am trying to run python script from VBA using shell. below is part of the sub and also the python codes. Program goes to the VBA function - ShellRunPython but it does not run python script. It does not execute the print in the python last statement.

My second issue is that assuming the python script is run successfully later, I need to get back value of PDFtext to variable str1 in sub. Thank you for suggestions

```vb
Sub RunPythonFromVBA()
    '............
    '............

     'Specify File Path
        sfilepath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
           
       pythonfilename = "CDAvsFAscript.py"
       xFilepath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
       xFilepath = Replace(xFilepath, "\", "\\")
        
        'Check for back slash
        If Right(sfilepath, 1) <> "\" Then
            sfilepath = sfilepath & "\"
        End If
            
        sFilename = Dir(sfilepath & "*.pdf")
        
        Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
            If Right(sFilename, 3) = "pdf" Then
                'Display file name in immediate window
        If sfilepath & "\" & sFilename Like "*052835022*" Then        

        xFilepath = xFilepath & sFilename
        ShellArg = "python " & sfilepath & pythonfilename & "" & " " & xFilepath
            Debug.Print ShellArg
            str1 = ShellRunPython(ShellArg)
        '................................
        '................................
        '................................
End Sub

    Public Function ShellRunPython(sCmd As String) As String
    
        'Run a shell command, returning the output as a string
    
        Dim oShell As Object
        Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    
        'run command
        Dim oExec As Object
        Dim oOutput As Object
        Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)
        Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut
    
        'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object
        Dim s As String
        Dim sLine As String
        While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
            sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
            If sLine <> "" Then s = s & sLine & vbCrLf
        Wend
    
        ShellRunPython = s
    
    End Function
```

.....................
.....................
Python script

```
import io

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()

    with io.StringIO() as retstr:
        with TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec,
                           laparams=laparams) as device:
            with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
                interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
                password = ""
                maxpages = 0
                caching = True
                pagenos = set()

                for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp,
                                              pagenos,
                                              maxpages=maxpages,
                                              password=password,
                                              caching=caching,
                                              check_extractable=True):
                    interpreter.process_page(page)

                return retstr.getvalue()


if __name__ == "__CDAvsFA__":
    #Filepath = 'C:\\passport all paged scan\\testPDF.pdf'
    PDFtext = convert_pdf_to_txt(xFilepath)
    print(PDFtext)
```

Comment: You're using both `xfilepath` and `sfilepath` ?

Comment: @ShriIyer: Removed the _shell_ tag from your question, because it is not about POSIX shell. If you want to invoke Python via, i.e., powershell, feel free to add _shell_ again to your tags, but then also add the specific tag for _powershell_ (or _cmd_ or whatever you are using).

Comment: @TimWilliams The variable xFilepath contains different value -
xFilepath = Replace(xFilepath, "\", "\\")

Comment: @user1934428 okay sure done. Removed Shell tag

Comment: `xFilepath` doesn't seem to be a variable that exists in your python script?  How are you getting the value for that?

Comment: @TimWilliams From what beginner's research I could do in python ; I want to get this xFilepath variable input from VBA.
Could you pls suggest how should I do it? Thanks

Comment: See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm and as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458304/pass-python-argument-through-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the guidance. I have one follow up. The thread you referred me to has this code which I modified to my needs. But I do not understand the relevance of this second statement -`f.write(b'some text')`  and also I do not understand whether I need to place these 2 statements on top of my already working python code?

 `import sys
    with 
 open(f'C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/PDFdataExtractor/{sys.argv[1]}', 'w') as f:
f.write(b'some text')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub RunPythonFromVBA()
    
    Dim sfilepath, scriptPath, sFilename, str1, ShellArg As String
    
    sfilepath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" 'Specify File Path
    
    scriptPath = sfilepath & "CDAvsFAscript.py"
    
    sFilename = Dir(sfilepath & "*052835022*.pdf")
    
    Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
        ShellArg = "C:\Python\Python39-32\python.exe """ & scriptPath & """ """ & sfilepath & sFilename & """"
        Debug.Print "Ran this: " & ShellArg
        
        str1 = ShellReturnOutput(ShellArg)
        Debug.Print "Got this: " & str1
        
        sFilename = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub

'Run a shell command, returning the output (or error) as a string
Public Function ShellReturnOutput(sCmd As String) As String
    Dim std, serr
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(sCmd)
        std = .Stdout.readall()
        serr = .Stderr.readall()
    End With
    ShellReturnOutput = IIf(serr <> "", serr, std)
End Function
```

With a very simple python script:

```python
import sys

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):

    return 'You passed in: '+path


Filepath = sys.argv[1]
PDFtext = convert_pdf_to_txt(Filepath)
print(PDFtext)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim It worked for me. I was able to remove all errors and got my job done. Thanks so much